# Searching for greek characters within a PDF document

Tags: pdf, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

I don't know how to search for greek letters in a pdf. How can I do this? Ideally I could do this within a pdf viewer software package.

From forum postings I've seen, the greek letters fall outside the standard unicode characters which are included in the pdf specification.

Comment: why can't you check if the letters match  [\u0391-\u03A9,\u03B1-\u03C9] ?

Comment: When I use the pdftotext command from xpdf, the greek characters come out as latin characters. I think this is because the pdftotext outputs in utf-8 which doesn't include greek alphabet [link](http://superuser.com/questions/220363/cleaning-up-pdftotext-font-issues) What pdf2text output setting could I use that would include greek characters?

Comment: Preferably though, I would search for these characters in a programme such as pdf-XChange viewer. I can only enter letters which I type into a search box, so I don't know how to indicate the fact that I want to search for a unicode encoding rather than the characters which make up the unicode encoding (e.g.\u0391) if you see what I mean.

Comment: as for your first comment, did you try "pdftotext -enc UTF-8 input.pdf output.txt" ?

Comment: ASCII7 seems to fix the ligature errors, but not the greek letters.

UTF-8 gives errors for both the f ligatures and the greek letters when I view it in emacs. Of course, I probably don't have the correct emacs add on, which may be the root of my problem.

Seeing the greek letters in emacs would not really solve my problem. I need an add-on to a software package like pdf-exchange, qiqqa or similar that allows searching for greek characters.

Comment: I couldn't find anything about this on planetpdf.com or pdfzone.com.

Comment: Did you check Apache pdfbox ? you'll might need to write some code but maybe it can solve your problem. http://pdfbox.apache.org/userguide/text_extraction.html, and an example here http://www.prasannatech.net/2009/01/convert-pdf-text-parser-java-api-pdfbox.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have worked out what I was doing wrong, and it was pretty basic.

I can search for a Greek letter just by using the character map or switching to the Greek alphabet keyboard e.g αβγ.

This generally finds the Greek characters. Many PDFs do not recognise Greek characters correctly though and instead have a gobbledygook approximation to the character with other shapes. This presumably depends on how the PDFs were made.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to at least search for the greek character σ in a pdf simply by going to its Wikipedia page, and copying and pasting it into the Acrobat Reader search window.